# does isomorphic Hasse diagrams represent two different posets or same poset?

Tags: order-theory

I want to have a clear picture of isomorphic hasse diagrams, what do they represent, same poset or two different posets?

Answer (score 0):

A Hasse diagram uniquely determines the relations in a partially ordered set, so two isomorphic Hasse diagrams represent two isomorphic posets, provided that they are isomorphic as directed graphs.